# Toggle & Set Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have trouble understand jquery. Was hoping someone could help me with setting a cookie from a toggle.

My script works the following way, the user `toggle();` and it changes the `class` which in-turn changes the Bootsrap grid layout from 4 columns (3) to 6 columns (2), This part works fine, but I wanted to add a cookie so it sets according to the user preference of chosen columns. Below is the js code for this:

```
// toggle click
//

$(".two, .three").click(function()
{                     
   $(".two, .three").toggle();
});

// Switch class and grid
//

$('.grid-toggle a').click(function(event) {
    $('.list-products li').removeClass('col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-6');

    if ($(this).hasClass('three')) {
        $('.list-products li').addClass('col-xs-4 col-sm-4');
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('two')) { //for less products
        $('.list-products li').addClass('col-xs-6 col-sm-6');
    }
    return false;
});
```

After a lot of research I am using the [Jquery-Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) tool but I am having trouble with integrating it into my current code. I have looked over the Basic usage but really cannot wrap my head around how to integrate it to my current script or where?

Below is my fiddle (with all dependencies included):

https://jsfiddle.net/panoplr/g68j6qfq/1/

Comment: Note that jquery-cookie is an older version. It is now js-cookie, and you can find [more information about it here](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.0.3#readme) (A key point is that it no longer requires the jQuery library, but most of us have jQuery installed regardless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a cookie using `jquery-cookie` plugin like this,

```
$.cookie("cookie_name", "value");
```

So you should be able to set a cookie and update it preferably when user performs the toggle like this,

```
if ($(this).hasClass('three')) {
    $('.list-products li').addClass('col-xs-4 col-sm-4');
    $.cookie("pref", '4X4');
}
if ($(this).hasClass('two')) { //for less products
    $('.list-products li').addClass('col-xs-6 col-sm-6');
    $.cookie("pref", '6X6');
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/74k4ndt1/)

**EDIT:**

If you want to use the cookie value to display the proper grid type, you should read the cookie value when the page loads(inside the `$(document).ready(function(){})` ) and change the classes accordingly like below,

```
var pref = $.cookie("pref");

if (pref == "4X4") {
    $('.list-products li').removeClass('col-xs-6 col-sm-6');
    $('.list-products li').addClass('col-xs-4 col-sm-4');
} else if(pref == "6X6"){
    $('.list-products li').removeClass('col-xs-4 col-sm-4');
    $('.list-products li').addClass('col-xs-6 col-sm-6');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I have tried this, however on a page reload it always reverts back to 4x4 columns. Do you think this could be due to ´.hasClass´ on the toggle button itself?

Comment: I have put an edit to the answer, check it and see whether is that what you need to achieve? [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/74k4ndt1/) is the working fiddle.